# Screenshots taken contain only black pixels

Tags: c#, .net, networking, screenshot, p2p

Why do I receive a black screen when using the following code to take a screenshot every 20 milliseconds and transmit it to a peer over an encrypted connection? (I am aware that 20 milliseconds is a bit fast of a refresh rate, but it seems that is not the problem. The processor and network can keep up quite well with the refresh rate, the problem is the fact that the bitmap appears completely black. EDIT: I now know it's some kinda strange network problem, but now the image shows up blurry, as though it's a bad analog signal. I have attached a screenshot of the program to this post. [[http://imgur.com/y9rWb.png](https://imgur.com/y9rWb.png)](https://imgur.com/y9rWb.png)

```
 P2PStream thestream = (P2PStream)sender;
        Bitmap mymap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics screenshotGFX = Graphics.FromImage(mymap);
        screenshotGFX.CopyFromScreen(new Point(),new Point(),new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height));
        Stream encryptedStream = networkLogic.getCryptoStream(thestream, true);
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                screenshotGFX.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                mymap.Save(encryptedStream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("A client has disconnected");
                break;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to print screen? The general screen or some movie?

Comment: I am trying to print the general screen. I am not viewing any video game, DRM'd music or video file, etc. Just the desktop and regular application windows.

Comment: This will likely not apply to you; however in the off-chance it does, I've had occasion where, after connecting to my computer via Citrix Remote Desktop, my clipboard seemed to get corrupted, images appeared all-black, and only a reboot resolved the issue.

Comment: It's not particular images which are black, the entire desktop is black. No windows or anything show up.

Comment: Have you tried just taking the screenshot every 20 ms and saving it, rather than transmitting it?  That will help narrow down the problem to either a screenshot issue or a data corruption issue during transport.

Comment: The P2P streaming software I am using contains checksumming algorithms to ensure that there are no transmission errors, and there are no problems with the checksums, so it does not appear to be a network-related error. I will save to a file just to make sure though

Comment: OK. It does appear to be a network error. After I saved it to a file, it showed up with no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to be a networking error with the router (faulty XSF support), and is now fixed.